# Struggling with a regex

Tags: regex

Trying to write a regex that, given a large string with any sort of characters, will match exactly 2 instances of a substring, say "ABC" followed by exactly 3 instances of another substring, say "XYZ".

For example the regex would match:

"ABCksdkfdkfsABCkkdaksdkXYZjdjsjdXYZXYZ"

I don't know where to start with this not being a regex expert. Interestingly CHAT GPT is an abject fail at this sort of question

Comment: Do you have to do this with a regexp alone?

Comment: What is the use case for this? It seems pretty random.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a negative lookahead that matches 3 `ABC`. Then match two occurrences of `ABC`. Follow this by a negative lookahead that matches more than three `XYZ`, and a normal match of exactly three `XYZ`.

```
^(?!(?:.*ABC){3})ABC.*ABC(?!(?:.*XYZ){4})(?:.*XYZ){3}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/KygFSz/1)

Comment: Added a negative lookahead for more than 2 ABC.

Comment: Thanks. It's always bugged me that `?<` turns into `?!<` when negating but `?=` doesn't turn into `?!=`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what flavour of regex you are trying to use.

It is easier with more powerful regex features but can be done with just simple features.

With whitespace to increase legibility:

```
^

(
    ([^AX]|A([^B]|$)|AB([^C]|$)|X([^Y]|$)|XY([^Z]|$))*
    ABC
){2}

(
    ([^AX]|A([^B]|$)|AB([^C]|$)|X([^Y]|$)|XY([^Z]|$))*
    XYZ
){3}

([^AX]|A([^B]|$)|AB([^C]|$)|X([^Y]|$)|XY([^Z]|$))*

$
```

The long complicated lines translate to:

- anything that isn't the first character of one of the two strings `ABC`,`XYZ`
- OR anything that is the first character not followed by the second
- OR anything that is the first two characters not followed by the third

```
    (
        [^AX]          |
        A   ( [^B]|$ ) |
        A B ( [^C]|$ ) |
        X   ( [^Y]|$ ) |
        X Y ( [^Z]|$ )
    )*
```

---

If you have lookaheads, this can be more simply written using `((?!(ABC|XYZ)).)*`:

```
^
(
    ((?!(ABC|XYZ)).)*
    ABC
){2}
(
    ((?!(ABC|XYZ)).)*
    XYZ
){3}
((?!(ABC|XYZ)).)*
$
```

and if you have `(DEFINE)` and recursive subpatterns:

```
^((?P>stuff)ABC){2}((?P>stuff)XYZ){3}(?P>stuff)$
(?(DEFINE)(?<stuff>((?!(ABC|XYZ)).)*))
```

Possessive quantifiers (eg. `*+`) can avoid some unnecessary backtracking:

```
^(((?!(ABC|XYZ)).)*+)(ABC(?1)){2}(XYZ(?1)){3}$
```

Comment: the requirements are underspecified so there are many interpretations of what should be matched. my regex match entire lines that "contain" the spec. something different is needed if multiple matches per line are required; or matches across lines are needed; or if matches must start `ABC` and end `XYZ`